# How to include EJB project into WAR project's classpath in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ejb, war, ear

I'm developing an EAR project which includes a WAR project and an EJB project as its modules.

(the project hierarchy in Eclipse is as follows:)

http://i44.tinypic.com/23koxuo.png

The WAR module wish to use some service class defined in the EJB module. How can I add the EJB module into WAR module's classpath in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Web Project > Select **Properties** > **Java Build Path**  > Click the **Projects** Tab and add the EJB Project.